# Python strange attribute

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes

Ive been taking online Python 3 course and there was an exercise.
You should write a class called Foo that has a property called x, which is set according to these rules:

- The initial value of x is 0 when creating the Foo class.
  When setting x with a number:
  If the number is nonnegative, the two digits to the right of it are stored in x.

  > > p=Foo()
  > >
  > > print(p.x) -----> output:0
  > >
  > > p.x=123
  > >
  > > print(p.x) -----> output :23

I just wondering how is the x getting the assignment through the object.

```
>>> p=Foo()
>>> p.x = 1234
>>> p.x == 34
True
>>> type(p.x)
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Read about properties e.g. [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo():
def __init__(self):
    self.n=0
@property
def x(self):
    return self.n
@x.setter
def x(self, num):

    if num<100 and num>=0:
        self.n=num
    elif num>100 and num%100!=0 :
        self.n=num%100
    elif num<0:
        self.n=-1
    else:
        self.n=0
```